# Not able to hide div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide few elements of my page. I am using document ready function of jquery. This function is as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ewd-feup-register-8").hide();
    $("#ewd-feup-register-input-8").hide();
});
```

My live page is [here](http://www.brainpointacademy.com/rssjal/registration/)

This field does not hide and in my browser console, it gives me an error. Please check it out and help me...

JQuery is loaded in the page... Please visit the actual page to get the problem. I can not post entire code here as it will be over the allowed limit.

Comment: what does the error say? have you tried googling how to fix + "error" ??

Comment: did you include the jquery script?

Comment: Please go to this link and check: http://www.brainpointacademy.com/rssjal/registration/

Comment: @Rayon Did you check my actual page?

Comment: it should be `function myfunction(){ ... }` you missed off the word `function`